# XMR-STAK - Does it detect CPU/GPU heat?

Tags: mining, cpu-mining, gpu-mining

Will xmr-stak stop working if it detects either the CPU or GPU temperatures are too high?

Similar to the configurable options in Claymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not. As of now, it doesn't monitor heat.